# Spark Scala Jaas configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, jaas

I’m executing spark code on scala shell using  Kafka jars and my intention is to stream messages from Kafka topic. My spark object is created but can anyone help me in how can I pass jaas configuration file while starting the spark shell ? My error point me to missing jaas configuration

Comment: How are you currently trying to pass it?

Comment: Scala>Spark-shell —jars=xxxxx.jar,xxxxx.jar —files=path/jaas.config

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a `spark-kafka.jaas` file in the current folder you are running `spark-submit` from, you pass it as a file, as well as a Driver and Executor option

```
spark-submit \
 ...
  --files "spark-kafka.jaas#spark-kafka.jaas" \
  --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./spark-kafka.jaas" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./spark-kafka.jaas"
```

You might also need to set `"security.protocol"` within the Spark code's Kafka properties to be one of the supported Kafka `SASL` protocols

Comment: I created a class but did not create a jar . I’m trying to run as below after starting spark shell and executing my code.  Scala>objectname.main(Array())

Comment: These arguments also apply to `spark-shell`

Comment: Getting file not found while using —file argument , it is looking for file name with #

Comment: @cricket_007 : I'm afraid it does not apply to spark-shell.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd They should. Feel free to provide your own answer if you think this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got an issue like yours, I'm using this startup-script to run my **spark-shell**, I'm using spark 2.3.0.

```
export HOME=/home/alessio.palma/scala_test

spark2-shell  \
--verbose \
--principal hdp_ud_appadmin \
--files "jaas.conf" \
--keytab $HOME/hdp_ud_app.keytab \
    --master local[2] \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.0.1 \ 
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/alessio.palma/scala_test/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf" \
    --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/alessio.palma/scala_test/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf" \
    --driver-java-options spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=file://jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=file:///etc/krb5.conf" \
    --driver-java-options spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=file://jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=file:///etc/krb5.conf" \
--queue=root.Global.UnifiedData.hdp_global_ud_app
```

Any attempt failed with this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
:
.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Jaas configuration not found
```

it looks like the `park.driver.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` are not working. Anything was failing until I added this row in top of my startup script:

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS='-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/alessio.palma/scala_test/jaas.conf'
```

And magically the jaas.conf file has been found. Another thing I suggest to add in your startup script is:

```
 export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10
```